# Finding points on surface with specified tangent planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that

$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{2-x} + \frac{1}{y-z} $

and let $S$ be the surface given by the equation

$f(x,y,z) = 1$

Are there any points on $S$ where the tangent plane to $S$ is parallel to the $xy$, $xz$ or $yz$–planes? If such points exist find them. If no such points exist, explain why.

Do we find the gradient vectors of both $S$ and the plane we are checking.

And find the values of $x,y,x$ such that one gradient vector is a scalar multiple of the other?

Would this be how we approach the question?